# How to tether WiFi-internetconnection with Nexus 7 on a PC without WLAN via USB?

Tags: usb, 4.1-jelly-bean, tethering, nexus-7, usb-tethering

With my Phone it worked via the normal settings. I want to perform tethering of the local WLAN my Nexus7 receives via USB to my computer.
I found this so far, but it doesn't seem very useful to me. Anyone any idea?

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1822788